# Leaflet map renderer L.svg changed already existing canvas markers

Tags: reactjs, svg, canvas, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have set renderer value L.svg with a padding of 100 for map as shown below

[image: React-Leaflet map with renderer option]

Before setting this option canvas markers were visible like this

[image: canvas marker before renderer option]

After setting renderer option markers are visible like this

[image: canvas marker after renderer option]

Code to render canvas marker is as follows

```
(function () {
var proto = L.Canvas.prototype;
var prev = proto._updateCircle;

proto._updateCircle = function (layer) {
    // only circleMARKER, not the standard circle
    if (layer instanceof L.Circle)
        return prev.call(this, layer);

    if (!this._drawing || layer._empty()) {
        return;
    }

    var p = layer._point,
        ctx = this._ctx,
        r = Math.max(Math.round(layer._radius), 1)
    //,s = (Math.max(Math.round(layer._radiusY), 1) || r) / r;

    var options = layer.options;

    var scale = Math.pow(2, this._map.getZoom()) * 256 / Math.PI / 6378137;
    scale = Math.pow(scale, options.boostExp) * options.boostScale;
    r = r * scale;
    if (!options.boostType) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        this._fillStroke(ctx, layer);
    }
    else switch (options.boostType) {
        case 'ball':
            if (options.fill) {
                if (options.stroke && options.weight !== 0)
                    r = r + options.weight * 0.5 * scale;
                let grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(p.x - r / 2, p.y - r / 2, 0, p.x, p.y, 1.5 * r);
                grd.addColorStop(0, options.fillColor);
                grd.addColorStop(1, options.color);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = grd;
                ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                ctx.fill(options.fillRule || 'evenodd');
            }
            break;
        case 'balloon':
            if (options.fill) {
                if (options.stroke && options.weight !== 0)
                    r = r + options.weight * 0.5 * scale;
                // this condition is used to identify if employee is at suggested location and draw a star on top of marker                     
                let grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(p.x - r / 2, p.y - r / 2 - 2 * r, 0, p.x, p.y - 2 * r, 2.5 * r);
                grd.addColorStop(0, options.fillColor);
                grd.addColorStop(1, options.color);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = grd;
                ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                ctx.lineTo(p.x - r, p.y - 2 * r);
                ctx.lineTo(p.x + r, p.y - 2 * r);
                ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
                ctx.arc(p.x, p.y - 2 * r, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill(options.fillRule = 'nonzero');                 
                if(options.suggestedLocation)
                    drawStar(p.x, p.y - 2 * r, 5, 3, 1.5, ctx);
            }
            break;
        case 'borderedball':
            if (options.fill) {
                if (options.stroke && options.weight !== 0)
                    r = r + options.weight * 0.5 * scale;
                let grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(p.x - r / 2, p.y - r / 2, 0, p.x, p.y, 1.5 * r);
                grd.addColorStop(0, options.fillColor);
                grd.addColorStop(1, options.color);
                ctx.beginPath();
                drawStar(p.x, p.y, 5, r, r, ctx);
                ctx.fillStyle = grd;
                ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                ctx.fill(options.fillRule || 'evenodd');
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (options.stroke && options.weight !== 0) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, r + options.weight * 0.5 * scale, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                ctx.fillStyle = options.color;
                ctx.fill(options.fillRule || 'evenodd');
            }

            if (options.fill) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, r - ((options.stroke && options.weight !== 0) ? options.weight * 0.5 * scale : 0), 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                ctx.fillStyle = options.fillColor || options.color;
                ctx.fill(options.fillRule || 'evenodd');
            }
    }
};

var xproto = L.CircleMarker.prototype;
var xprev = xproto._containsPoint;

xproto._containsPoint = function (p) {
    if (this instanceof L.Circle)
        return xprev.call(this, p);

    var r = this._radius;

    var options = this.options;
    var scale = Math.pow(2, this._map.getZoom()) * 256 / Math.PI / 6378137;
    scale = Math.pow(scale, options.boostExp) * options.boostScale;
    r = r * scale;
    r = r + (this.options.stroke ? this.options.weight * scale / 2 : 0);

    if (options.boostType === 'balloon')
        p = new L.Point(p.x, p.y + 2 * r);

    return p.distanceTo(this._point) <= r + this._clickTolerance();
    // clickTolerance only for mobile! (seems to be fixed with LL1.4)
    // return p.distanceTo(this._point) <= r + ((L.Browser.touch && L.Browser.mobile) ? 10 : 0);
};

var cproto = L.Layer.prototype;
var cprev = cproto._openPopup;
cproto._openPopup = function (e) {
    var layer = e.layer || e.target;

    if (!(layer instanceof L.CircleMarker) || (layer instanceof L.Circle))
        return cprev.call(this, e);

    if (!this._popup) {
        return;
    }

    if (!this._map) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent map click
    L.DomEvent.stop(e);
    // treat it like a marker and figure out
    // if we should toggle it open/closed
    if (this._map.hasLayer(this._popup) && this._popup._source === layer) {
        this.closePopup();
    } else {
        this.openPopup(layer._latlng);
        layer.on('preclick', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
    }
};

var pproto = L.Popup.prototype;
var p_getAnchor = pproto._getAnchor;
pproto._getAnchor = function () {
    if (!(this._source instanceof L.CircleMarker) || this._source instanceof L.Circle)
        return p_getAnchor.call(this);
    var r = this._source._radius;
    var options = this._source.options;
    //var zoomScale;
    var scale = Math.pow(2, this._map.getZoom()) * 256 / Math.PI / 6378137;
    scale = Math.pow(scale, options.boostExp) * options.boostScale;
    if (options.boostType === 'balloon')
        r = 2.5 * r * scale;
    else
        r = 0.5 * r * scale;
    // Where should we anchor the popup on the source layer?
    return L.point(this._source && this._source._getPopupAnchor ? this._source._getPopupAnchor() : [0, -r]);
};
})();

function drawDiamond(context, x, y, width, height) {
context.moveTo(x, y);
// top left edge
context.lineTo(x - width / 2, y + height / 2);
// bottom left edge
context.lineTo(x, y + height);
// bottom right edge
context.lineTo(x + width / 2, y + height / 2);
}

function drawStar(cx, cy, spikes, outerRadius, innerRadius, ctx) {
var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
var x = cx;
var y = cy;
var step = Math.PI / spikes;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(cx, cy - outerRadius)
for (let i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
    x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
    y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y)
    rot += step

    x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
    y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y)
    rot += step
}
ctx.lineTo(cx, cy - outerRadius);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
ctx.fill();
}
```

Please suggest a solution to render canvas markers as they were before setting renderer value to L.svg.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are creating the circles, there you can set the renderer back to canvas. `L.circleMarker(latlng, {renderer: L.canvas()})`

Comment: @FalkeDesign thanks tried your solution it is degrading the performance of the application making it more slow

Comment: Try to use the same canvas renderer for each circle-marker `var canvas = L.canvas(); L.circleMarker(latlng, {renderer: canvas})`